# Ограничить количество символов строки при отображении страницы

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, jinja2

Как в Flask при выводе из базы:

**views.py**

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app
from app.models import News, Event, User
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

some_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///app.db')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)
session = Session()


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
return render_template("index.html",
                       title='Головна',
                       anews=session.execute('SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6) subn ORDER BY id ASC'))
```

**шаблон index.html**

```
{% for news in anews %}
  <article class="news-block card">
    <div class="news">
      <div
          style="background: url({{ url_for('.static', filename = 'images/fornews.jpg') }});background-size: cover;background-position-y: 50%;"
          class="news-picture">
        <div><span class="date">{{ news.date }}</span></div>
        <div class="image-shadow"><span class="title"><a href="news-page ">{{ news.title }}<span
            class="badge badge-warning">Hot news</span></a>
                  <p class="author">{{ news.author }}</p>
                  </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="news-text">
        {{ news.description }}
      </div>
      <a href="news-page " class="btn btn-md pull-right">Читати повністтю</a></div>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Требуется ограничить `news.description` до 120 символов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это значит в качестве шаблонизатора вы используете **Jinja2**? если так, то вам прийдется по душе кастомный фильтр.
Он представляет собой обычную функцию `python`, которая в шаблоне будет выглядеть так `{{ news.description|make_shorter(120) }}`.

Сам фильтр определяем следующим образом:

```
import textwrap

def make_shorter( filtering_str, filtering_width=100):
    return textwrap.shorten(filtering_str, width=filtering_width, placeholder="...")
```

И регистрируем наш фильтр в *environment*:

`environment.filters['make_shorter'] = make_shorter`